# WebStorm push failed to GitHub. Can't find repository

Tags: github, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm and trying to push to my GitHub repository. This was working fine before, but now I'm getting that my repository is not found. I'm assuming this is because of GitHub changing their policy: https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

I downloaded the latest version of WebStorm 2018.1.1 hoping that the issue would be fixed, but I'm still getting the error. Is there any way I can fix this within WebStorm?

Comment: Perhaps, I was jumping the gun. It appears that my pushes are working, but I'm still getting the error message in webstorm. I guess I can live with this.

Answer (score 1):

If the crypto removal is the cause of your trouble, try at least to switch to an SSH URL and see if the issue persists.

See "[Using Git integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-git-integration.html)". I would recommend, for testing, to generate an ssh key without passphrase, and registering the public one to your GitHub account.
See GitHub documentation about SSH.